# How to add a printer connected to windows machine in ubuntu

Tags: windows, printing

I am using `ubuntu 16.04`. I need to connect to windows printer. The printer is connected to windows 7 machine with IP address of `192.168.2.5` and my IP address is `192.168.1.98`. How can I connect to that printer.?

[image]

As you can see in the above image, there are no printer listed with ip `192.168.2.5`

Comment: Did you try to select `Windows Printer via SAMBA`?

Comment: this is a long time ago; the printer to be connected to is HP Laser Jet pro MFP M126NW; I can see it listed in the top image; can one not click on one of those listings?

Answer (score 0):

In the Ubuntu Settings, under the Printers menu, select `Network Printer` and your printer should appear. You can add it from there. The IP of the Windows machine, or your Ubuntu machine for that matter, doesn't affect anything. This just identifies the device on the network.

Comment: I am doing the same steps as you described.But it is not finding the the printer

Comment: Printer make and model?

Comment: HP Laser Jet pro MFP M126NW.

Comment: I have added an image. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I see. Have you tried the `Find Network Printer` option?

Comment: Pardon me if you have already found this. It is the HP linux driver page for your model. [ http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_pro_mfp_m126nw.html].  They also have installation instructions for the package. In past experience, there is a shell script in the package that you can run that will locate the printer on the network, and install the correct driver locally. which will then show up in the add-printer dialog.  I don't have direct experience with this particular package. But, it stands to reason they would be consistent. Anyway - Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

some would say you need samba; as this ubuntu guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

........ you are windows 7 but this recent post said with windows 10, one might not need samba https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=242406&p=1297669&hilit=samba#p1297669

. it talked of using mDNS  ... "Windows 10 is the very first windows that can speak mDNS which both Apple and Linux machines use natively."

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing and wasn't able to add a printer via the network so, with a little googling I ended up using Goolge Cloud Print.Very quick and easy.